# What is the role of the "Service Broker" in SOA?

Tags: soa

What is the role of the "Service Broker" in SOA Model Architecture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The service broker is meant to be a registry of services, and stores information about what services are available and who may use them. For example, UDDI which was originally conceived as a web service registry is now considered a SOA Service Broker.

Comment: Thank's but Why SOA needs UDDI or Service Broker?

Comment: Typically you would use one to register services you want other parties to be able to discover. It also sometimes serves as a documentation point for your services.

Comment: would you please tell me(or give me a link) how can i implement a Service Broker?

Comment: Um, thats a non-trivial task. I recommend you look at some open source alternatives like SoapUDDI - http://soapuddi.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 4):

SOA registry is responsible for registering business services, while SOA broker is responsible for orchestrating the connections between these components.. The service broker reads the interface information from the registry and then makes the right connection to other interfaces.